# Reducing Boilerplate Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm currently using Ducks Pattern in my Redux-Thunk application. However, it seems there are a lot of repetitive codes inside Action Creators that I see. I have more fetch logics and it's similar to the code below.  How can I make my code cleaner and get rid of repetitive boilerplates ? Also, is it better to load all fetch using Promise.all or run each fetch by calling inside componentDidMount?

```js
/* 
@ ACTION TYPES 
*/
const FETCH_BIRTHDAY_LOAD = "FETCH_BIRTHDAY_LOAD";
const FETCH_BIRTHDAY_SUCCESS = "FETCH_BIRTHDAY_SUCCESS";

const FETCH_ANNIVERSAY_LOAD = "FETCH_ANNIVERSAY_LOAD";
const FETCH_ANNIVERSAY_SUCCESS = "FETCH_ANNIVERSAY_SUCCESS"
const FETCH_FAILED = "FETCH_FAILED";
/* 
@ Action Creator
*/
export const fetchBirthday = () => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({type : FETCH_BIRTHDAY_LOAD , payload : FETCH_BIRTHDAY_LOAD});
        return fetch(`${EMPLOYEE_URI}?stype=birthday`)
            .then(response => response.json().then(data => dispatch({ type:          FETCH_BIRTHDAY_SUCCESS, payload: data })))
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({ type: FETCH_FAILED, payload: { name: FETCH_BIRTHDAY_LOAD, errorMessage: err.message } })
            })  
    }           
}
             


export const fetchAnniversary = () => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ANNIVERSAY_LOAD, payload: FETCH_BIRTHDAY_LOAD });
        
        return fetch(`${ENDPOINT.EMPLOYEE}`)
            .then(response => response.json().then(data => dispatch({ type: FETCH_ANNIVERSAY_SUCCESS, payload: data })))
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({ type: FETCH_FAILED, payload: { name: FETCH_ANNIVERSAY_LOAD, errorMessage: err.message } })
            })  
    }
}

/*
@ Initial State
*/
const initialState = {
    birthAnniversaryData: [],
    anniversaryData: [],
    error : null
}


export default function home( state = initialState , action){

    const {type, payload } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case FETCH_BIRTHDAY_LOAD :
            return {...state, isLoading : true, error : null}

        case FETCH_ANNIVERSAY_LOAD :
            return { ...state, isLoading: true, error: null }
    case FETCH_BIRTHDAY_SUCCESS : 
        return { ...state, birthAnniversaryData: payload, }

    case FETCH_ANNIVERSAY_SUCCESS : 
        return {...state, workAnniversaryData : payload, }
        case FETCH_FAILED:
            return { error: payload }

        default : 
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which includes utilities to simplify several common Redux use cases, including store setup, defining reducers, immutable update logic, and even creating entire "slices" of state at once.  Its `createSlice` API automatically generates action creators for you, eliminating the need to write them by hand.  It also has a `createAsyncThunk` API that handles dispatching actions based on a promise.

Your code could be simplified down to:

```js
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const fetchBirthday = createAsyncThunk(
  'dates/fetchBirthday',
  async () => {
    return fetch(`${EMPLOYEE_URI}?stype=birthday`).then(res => res.json());
  }
);

const fetchBirthday = createAsyncThunk(
  'dates/fetchAnniversay',
  async () => {
    return fetch(`${ENDPOINT.EMPLOYEE}`).then(res => res.json());
  }
);

const initialState = {
    birthAnniversaryData: [],
    anniversaryData: [],
    error : null
}

const dateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "dates",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // add reducers that manipulate the data here. These will generate
    // corresponding action creators automatically.
    // Reducers use Immer, so you can "mutate" the state safely.
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    // Handle any actions that were not defined in the slice here
    
    builder.addCase(fetchBirthday.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.error = null;
    })
    
    builder.addCase(fetchBirthday.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.error = null;
    });
    
    builder.addCase(fetchBirthday.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.birthAnniversaryData = action.payload;
    });
    
    builder.addCase(fetchAnniversary.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.workAnniversaryData = action.payload;
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: I'll be using the redux toolkit, but I would like to know if my code could become more readable without the repetitive codes. Also in the code above does the createAsyncThunk method handle the error or do I have to wrap around with try catch to catch the fetch error? Thanks

Comment: `createAsyncThunk` bases its response on whether the returned promise is fulfilled or rejected. `fetch()` will throw errors / return a rejected promise if there's an actual network error, but not on an HTTP 400/500 response code. That's why most wrappers around `fetch` _do_ throw errors on an HTTP 400/500.